# dynamically loading routes in vuejs not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Am working on a project, i want to dynamically load my routes only when its needed instead of loading all the components when the page loads, in route.js here is my code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)
function loadView(view){
    return () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "view[request]" */`@/components/${view}.vue`)
}
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {path: '/', name: 'home', component: loadView('Notlogin/HelloWorld')}, 
    { path: '/add', name: 'add', component: loadView('login/add'), meta:{requireAuth:true}},
    { path: '/add/:id', name: 'addParams', component: loadView('login/add'), alias: '/add', meta:{requireAuth:true}},
    { path: '/dashboard', name: 'dashboard', component: loadView('login/dashboard'), meta:{requireAuth:true}},
    { path: '/profile', name: 'profile', component: loadView('login/profile/index'), meta:{requireAuth:true}},
    { path: '/projectDetails/:id', name: 'projectDetails', component: loadView('login/projectDetails'), meta:{requireAuth:true}},
    { path: '/Projects', name: 'Projects', component: loadView('login/urProjects'), meta:{requireAuth:true}},
    { path: '/projectCat/:id', name: 'projectCat', component: loadView('login/projectCat'), meta:{requireAuth:true}},
    { path: '/Finance', name: 'Finance', component: loadView('login/Finance'), meta:{requireAuth:true}},
    { path: '/login',name: 'login', component: loadView('Notlogin/login')},
    { path: '/forgot',name: 'forgot', component: loadView('Notlogin/forgot')},
    { path: '/register', name: 'register', component: loadView('Notlogin/register')},
    { path: '/test', name: 'test', component:  loadView('test')},
    { path: '/404', name: '404', component: loadView('Notlogin/404') }, 
    { path: '*', redirect: error404} 
  ]
})
export default router
```

the problem is that i keep getting this error in the console

```
warning  in ./src/components/login/profile/Profile.vue

There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other c
ase-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\De Stone of David\Desktop\node projects\vuejs\myapp\client\node_modul
es\vue-loader\index.js??ref--0!C:\Users\De Stone of David\Desktop\node projects\
vuejs\myapp\client\src\components\login\profile\Profile.vue
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\De Stone of David\Desktop\node projects\vuejs\myapp\client\node_mod
ules\babel-loader\lib\index.js!C:\Users\De Stone of David\Desktop\node projects\
vuejs\myapp\client\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\selector.js?type=script&index=0!C
:\Users\De Stone of David\Desktop\node projects\vuejs\myapp\client\src\component
s\login\profile\profileDeftails.vue
* C:\Users\De Stone of David\Desktop\node projects\vuejs\myapp\client\node_modul
es\vue-loader\index.js??ref--0!C:\Users\De Stone of David\Desktop\node projects\
vuejs\myapp\client\src\components\login\profile\profile.vue
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\De Stone of David\Desktop\node projects\vuejs\myapp\client\src\comp
onents lazy /^\.\/.*\.vue$/
```

pls what am i doing wrong or how can i solve this problem thanks

Comment: Might have something to do with your dev environment?  https://forum.vuejs.org/t/resolved-there-are-multiple-modules-with-names-that-only-differ-in-casing/26627/5

Comment: This warning occurs when you're importing files with different cases 
eg: given Files A, B, C in same folder..
in file A: import 'c' , 
in file B: import 'C' ...  In short, i'm not sure this is your root problem..